# How to implement an iterator to a CyclicList?

Tags: c++, iterator

Having the following implementation of `CyclicList` :

```
struct LItem {
  LItem* next;
  LItem* prev;
};

class CyclicList {
public:
  LItem* Remove(LItem* item) {
    if(root == item) {
      root = root->prev;
      if(root == item) {
        root = nullptr;
        item->next = item->prev = nullptr;
        return item;
      }
    }
    item->next->prev = item->prev;
    item->prev->next = item->next;
    item->next = item->prev = nullptr;
    return item;
  }
  LItem* Insert(LItem* item) {
    if(root) {
      item->next = root->next;
      item->prev = root;
      item->next->prev = item;
      item->prev->next = item;
    } else
      item->next = item->prev = item;
    root = item;
    return item;
  }

public:
  class Iterator {
  public:
    void operator++();
    LItem* operator*();
    bool operator!=(const Iterator&);
  };
  Iterator Begin();
  Iterator End();

private:
  LItem* root;
};
```

Is it possible to implement an `iterator` (together with `Begin` and `End`) such that both of following 2 snippets are working

```
size_t count = 0;
for( auto it=list.Begin() ; it != list.End() ; ++it )
    ++count;
for( auto it=list.Begin() ; it != list.End() ; ++it )
    delete list.Remove(*it);
```

?

My attempt so far is as follows:

add this to `CyclicList`

```
LItem* end;
CyclicList() : root(nullptr), end(new LItem) {}
~CyclicList() { delete end; }
```

`Iterator`, `Begin` and `End` implementation:

```
  class Iterator {
    LItem* beg;
    LItem* p;
    bool done;

  public:
    void operator++() {
      p = p->next;
      if(p == beg) done = true;
    }
    LItem* operator*() { return p; }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) { return !(rhs.p == p) || done != rhs.done; }
    Iterator(LItem* p, bool done) : beg(p), p(p), done(done) {}
  };

  Iterator Begin() { return Iterator(root, false); };
  Iterator End() { return Iterator(root, true); };
```

and it allows me to do this:

```
{
  CyclicList list;
  LItem* first = new LItem();
  LItem* second = new LItem();
  list.Insert(first);
  list.Insert(second);

  size_t count = 0;
  for(auto it = list.Begin(); it != list.End(); ++it) ++count;

  assert(count == 2);

  delete first;
  delete second;
}
{
  CyclicList list;
  LItem* first = new LItem();
  LItem* second = new LItem();
  list.Insert(first);
  list.Insert(second);
  delete list.Remove(*list.Begin());
  delete list.Remove(*list.Begin());
}
```

But gives heap use after free (which pointr to `operator++` line: `p = p->next;`) on this:

```
  CyclicList list;
  LItem* first = new LItem();
  list.Insert(first);
  for(auto it = list.Begin(); it != list.End(); ++it) {
    delete list.Remove(*it);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For iterators, it is usually not a good idea to modify the container while iterating on it.

`it` is still on `first` when you delete it. When executing `++it`, `it.p->next` is undefined (behavior). On my machine `it.p->next` is different from `first` and so `it.done` is not set to `true`. The next `delete` delete an undefined pointer, so the error.

Except from this point, I am not sure that you really need an allocation for the `end` cell. Your iterator mainly works with its field `done`.